# Python with Selenium and Chrome - default profile, cannot search url

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

When I open a new instance of Chrome using Selenium, I am no longer able to open a website. My code is fairly simple at the moment:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Chrome opens up with my profile loaded, but nothing happens, and I get following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Dropbox/Python/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

Now if I don't set it up to open up a default profile, everything works as expected:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

My chromedriver.exe is located where the executable_path states, but I also have it set as an environmental variable. I don't think I need executable_path argument in the first code, but not sure.

Does anyone know what is the reason why driver.get() doesn't work?

Comment: I do not think it is driver.get() that was not working, it must be caused by your Chrome Options. Your Chrome instance did not even start.

Comment: Chrome did opened up, with my profile (all plugins where loaded). I am not sure why it says "Chrome failed to start".